# How to detect if Qt is OpenGL or Angle version in qmake project?

Tags: windows, opengl, qt5, qmake, qt5.2

I want to detect if the Qt version is using OpenGL or Angle on Windows, for puposes of having `nmake install` working correctly. This is what I have now, snippet from a .pro file:

```
GLTMP = $$[QT_HOST_PREFIX]
contains(GLTMP, ".*_opengl") {
    message(Detected OpenGL)
} else {
    message(Did not detect OpenGL so assuming Angle)
    # add Angle DLL files to INSTALLS
}
```

Now this only works if QT_HOST_PREFIX actually contains `_opengl` for OpenGL version, but not for Angle version (for example `C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl` vs. `C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl`), but obviously this is not very robust.

**Is there a way, which does not depend on path strings?**

Desired result is to have Qmake produce correct makefile, so `nmake install` does the right thing.

Comment: IIRC angle has a D3DCompiler_43.dll along with the dlls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains(QT_CONFIG, angle)` should give you the proper result.

I know it's been a while since the question was asked but I stumbled over this page when looking for exactly that thing and thought that I might help others that have the same problem :)